# Series Divergence - Apostol Calculus Vol I, Section 10.20 #10

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series converges absolutely, conditionally or diverges.

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln (e^{n}+e^{-n})}\ $.

I have tried manipulating the series, integral test and partial sums. But I can't come up with the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we have
$$\frac{1}{\ln(e^n+e^{-n})}=\frac{1}{n+\ln(1+e^{-2n})}\sim\frac{1}{n},\quad\text{as }n\to\infty,$$
which implies $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\ln(e^n+e^{-n})}$ diverges, i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(e^n+e^{-n})}$ does not converge absolutely.

Note that $e^x+e^{-x}$ is increasing respect to $x$ when $x>0$ (differentiate directly), then we know $\displaystyle\left\{\frac{1}{\ln(e^n+e^{-n})}\right\}$ is monotonic decreasing and tending to $0$. Hence by Leibniz's test, we know that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(e^n+e^{-n})}$ converges. Thus, it converges conditionaly.